# Iterating through nested dictionary; retrieve nested value but keep key names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My latest use of PyPDF2 extracted all fields as a nested dictionary. I am looking at roughly 70 keys that I want to make into a simple df (and then a .csv file.) Here is a sample of my data- with 2 keys.

```
{'Proposed Arrangement': {'/FT': '/Ch',
  '/T': 'Proposed Arrangement',
  '/TU': 'Please select an arrangement from the drop-down list.',
  '/Ff': 4325376,
  '/V': 'Remote – Within the Local Commuting Area',
  '/DV': 'Remote – Within the Local Commuting Area'},
 'Proposed Length of Arrangement': {'/FT': '/Ch',
  '/T': 'Proposed Length of Arrangement',
  '/TU': 'Please select the proposed length of the arrangement from the drop-down list.',
  '/Ff': 71434240,
  '/V': '6 Months',
  '/DV': 'Please select length'}}
```

I am trying to make a for loop to clean the dict and by pulling on the '/V' keys. Ideally, the new dict would have this output:

```
{'Proposed Arrangement': 'Remote – Within the Local Commuting Area',
 'Proposed Length of Arrangement':'6 Months'}
```

Does anyone have any idea of where to start with this loop? I'm a bit of a beginner and most of the resources I found were extracting ONLY the values (e.g. [Remote - Within the Local Commuting Area, 'Six Months]) and this isn't what I need. I want to keep the first keys to eventually become my column headers when I switch the cleaned dict into a df. Thanks!

Comment: `new_dict = {k: v['/V'] for k, v in old_dict.items()}`

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! But I am getting a key error possibly because not all values have '/V'. If that's the case, how would I leave no '/V' as Null?

Comment: `new_dict = {k: v.get('/V') for k, v in old_dict.items()}` will work because `.get()` returns `None` if the key is not present.

Comment: Yup, that did it. That was almost too easy, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In a bit convoluted way... This should help you.

```
input_dict = {'Proposed Arrangement': 
            {'/FT': '/Ch', 
            '/T': 'Proposed Arrangement', 
            '/TU': 'Please select an arrangement from the drop-down list.',
            '/Ff': 4325376,
            '/V': 'Remote - Within the Local Commuting Area',
            '/DV': 'Remote - Within the Local Commuting Area'},
          'Proposed Length of Arrangement': 
            {'/FT': '/Ch',
            '/T': 'Proposed Length of Arrangement',
            '/TU': 'Please select the proposed length of the arrangement from the drop-down list.',
            '/Ff': 71434240,
            '/V': '6 Months',
            '/DV': 'Please select length'}
            }

output_dict = {}
for key in input_dict.keys():
    nested_dict = input_dict[key]
    output_dict[key] = nested_dict['/V']

print(output_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Steven Rumbalski provides this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974108/iterating-through-nested-dictionary-retrieve-nested-value-but-keep-key-names#comment127180298_71974108) above. But here is a slight improvement where the value is only included *if* it exists, rather than including the empty `None` value.

```py
new_dict = {k: v.get('/V') for k, v in old_dict.items() if v.get('/V') is not None}
```